# How do you activate an else statement after a web3.js call is thrown?

Tags: web3js

**General purpose of code:**

I am trying to create a helper function that returns `true` if an element exists in a dynamic array in solidity, and `false` if an element does not exist at a certain index location. The purpose of this function is to help the `findLastIndexLocation` function determine the length of a dynamic array.

**Problem I am having:**

When I call the index location of an element that does not exist (because we reached the end of the dynamic array), the call is `Thrown` and there is an `Error` message.

**Concise question for you:**

I would like to include logic in the `if` statement of the `checkIndex` function to detect this `throw` and return `false`.

Can you help me with that?

```
// the goal of the code below is to detect the last index location in a solidity array
// Note: from my understanding, solidity cannot return arrays

// this variable exists to catch the last index location of a certain array
let lastIndexLocation = null;

// this is a "helper" function for the findLastIndexLocation function below
let checkIndex = async (account, index) => {
    if(await contractInstance.methods.notary(account, index)
        .call((error, result) => { 
            // issue is in this code block
            // if result.timestamp or result.digitalFingerprint is undefined, a Throw takes place.
            if(result.timestamp && result.digitalFingerprint) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
        })
    ){
        return true
    } else { 
        return false
    {
};


let findLastIndexLocation = async (account) => {
    index = 0;

    // start with if statement to check if an array even exists
    if ( await checkIndex(account, index) != true) {
        return 'empty array: no entries where recorded'; 
    } else {
        while(await checkIndex(account, index)) {
            if(await checkIndex(account, index)) {
                index++;
            } else {
                lastIndexLocation = index - 1;
                return lastIndexLocation;
            }
        } 
    }
};
```

Comment: To begin with, `checkIndex` should be `async`. Then, you should `await` before calling `contractInstance.notary`. Finally, you should `await` before calling `checkIndex`. Please start with that and report back if there are any other issues.

Comment: You did not change anything in your question. Am I supposed to guess what you did in your actual code??? You're obviously missing an `await` somewhere!

Comment: I added `async` and `await`. I also used web3@v1.2.1 this time. It still throws an error in the `if` statement when it reaches the end of the dynamic array. I also made the changes in the actual code. How do I return `false` when this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
async function checkIndex(account, index) {
    try {
        const result = await contractInstance.methods.notary(account, index).call();
        return result.timestamp && result.digitalFingerprint;
    }
    catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The catch() function was what I was missing.